# Using androidx NotificationManagerCompat cannot resolve symbol 'from'

Tags: android, notifications, androidx

Using `NotificationManagerCompat` in a Java class that extends `JobService`, I am getting 'cannot resolve from' error. Did 'Invalidate and Restart' but nothing happened.

Here is my code:

```
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;


public class DailyNotificationJob extends JobService {

    JobParameters paramic;
    Boolean jobCancelled = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        new postRequest().execute(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        jobCancelled = true;
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public class postRequest extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
 
//SOME CODE WAS REMOVED

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String postDatareceived) {

                            // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
                            Intent intent = new Intent(DailyNotificationJob.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(DailyNotificationJob.this, 0, intent, 0);

                            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(DailyNotificationJob.this, "1")
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.rocket)
                                    .setContentTitle("Search Console Update")
                                    .setContentText(body)
                                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = new NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
                            notificationManagerCompat.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), builder.build());

                        }
                    }


                } 
                jobFinished(paramic,true);

        }

    }

 

}
```

notificationmanagercompact cannot resolve symbol from:
[image: notificationmanagercompact cannot resolve symbol from]

Comment: Question resolved, i added 'new' to NotificationManagerCompact which was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Remove "New"

`NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat =  NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);`